# How do I get typed.js to work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typed.js

I am trying to get typed.js to work and for some reason I just can't get it.

In the header

```
<script src="/typed.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the code

```
 <script>
$(function(){
    $(".element").typed({
        strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
        typeSpeed: 0
    });
});
</script>
<h1><span class="element">test</span></h1>
```

I took the code right off GitHub. What am I missing?

Comment: Swap the order of your scripts in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypedJS requires jQuery to be loaded in order to work correctly. Simply swap the order of the scripts in your `<head>` section:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/typed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(assuming your path to `typed.js` is accurate)

Comment: I am just starting out and didn't realize that was required. That is a mistake I will not make again. Thank You.