# I don't understand the $(".element").typed() notation

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below, I don't understand how the notation:  $(".element").typed() works.  I understand that $(".element") refers to the id of a <div> element.  However, appending   .typed()  to it seems to assume that typed() is a method of the class <div>.  I don't see how that can be.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/typed.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script>
$(function(){
    $(".element").typed({
        strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
        typeSpeed: 0
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I assume typed() is a jQuery plugin?

Comment: It seems like you need to read a short tutorial on jQuery, which is what is providing the `$` function in this case. The `$` method returns jQuery object, not a DOM element, and all the methods invoked (such as `typed` in this case) are either part of jQuery, or part of some jQuery plugin.

Comment: typed appears to be THIS jQuery library: https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/

Comment: `$(...)` refers to a _jQuery object_, which happens to reference in this case a DOM element.  `.typed()` therefore runs some jQuery functions (from the library mentioned above) against the jQuery object, probably animating letters as though being "typed on a keyboard" in that DOM element.

Answer (score 3):

***#1***

> $(".element") refers to the id of a  element

actually a dot refers to a dom element class. for IDs it's `#`.

***#2***

jQuery brought you the jquery objects for dom elements he found  with that class and tries to implement on them the function `typed()` - which isn't a jquery function maybe you mean [type()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type/) . you probably have a typo or using an external plugin for jquery. **update** it was pointed out to me that `typed` is indeed a plugin which i did not see was imported. tnx

read more on jquery and how you use it. what it gives you back and how can you manipulate data received.

https://jquery.com/

Comment: Your language is confusing, actually: `$('.element')` - refers to _a DOM element_, as grabbed by jQuery, using a _class_ selector.  Not really the "id of an element".  And #2, after some Google searching, it's a strong guess that typed refers to this library: https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/

Comment: @cale_b that's what i said. `$('.element')` will bring you a jqueryobject refered to the dom element by it's class. and `#` for finding by id. sorry about my english. thanks for clarifying if someone didn't understand me

Comment: ".typed" is not a "typo"  Please also see:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408952/how-do-i-get-typed-js-to-work-properly

Comment: @BrianE "you probably have a typo or using an external plugin for jquery." didn't want to assume but now i do see you did import it in example. thanks i'll update my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see - you are _quoting_ OP, then correcting them.  Got it now - wasn't clear at first.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that typed.js is an extension of jquery.  This link provides an excellent discussion on the topic.

https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Thanks one and all!